# Cartthrob Lite Problem

Tags: cartthrob

After installing cart throb lite and default templates, on testing the default checkout page and hitting the checkout button, I get the following error:

```
Error Number: 1364

Field 'title' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `exp_channel_titles` (`entry_id`, `site_id`, `channel_id`, `author_id`, `forum_topic_id`, `ip_address`, `status`, `versioning_enabled`, `entry_date`, `edit_date`, `year`, `month`, `day`) VALUES ('', '1', '2', 1, 0, '::1', 'closed', 'y', 1394557211, '20140311130111', '2014', '03', '11')

Filename: third_party/cartthrob/models/cartthrob_entries_model.php

Line Number: 261
```

The entry id is going as null, even though on_the_fly="yes" is set in the template.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been up against this.
Check your `sql_mode` doesn't have `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` enabled.